# Which implementation of InteractiveObject that is lightweight should I use to keep track of mousefocus in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a spark List control that shows a side-list on *ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OVER* event. Basicaly it shows the contents of the item you are hovering. I would be also using *ListEvent.ITEM_ROLL_OU*T to hide it again but I want the user to be able to click on it (the sidelist) too.

So, i use *MouseEvent.ROLL_OU*T and check the *event.relatedObject*'s id to see where the cursor went. I added an invisible Rectangle overlaying the sidelist that's a bit larger so it gains focus 1st. But it doesn't.

Googling around, I think that the Spark Rectangle cant gain focus as it doesn't implement InteractiveObject. What should I use?

My logic:

```
protected function listOUT(event:MouseEvent):void
{
     var obj:Object = event.relatedObject;
     if (obj.id != "focusRect")
     {
         sidelist.visible = false;
     }
}
```

My struggle is to keep the side-list visible if the user moves the cursor from the main list to the sidelist.
Any other suggestions outside my approach are also welcome.

**Update**
(image link)
[Red are the invisible Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy8wD.png)

Comment: I have an idea. But I admit I don't know what a spark list is. Question: what event should happen when the user clicks on the side list?

Comment: It's just a list, the standard one. The other variation of a list in AFlashBuilder is the mx list. There will be a MouseEvent.CLICK, but it's not the problem as it is straightforward *dispatch-event* to *event-listener* action.

Comment: I see. You can't click on the list because it is disappearing when you roll on to it. Hmm... can you do something like a Boolean that responds to x and y coords of the mouse on the stage?

Comment: I thought about it and it seemed complicated. if no one comes with a better solution I'll do it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- On roll_over select the item in the mainlist, display the sidelist
  based on the selecteditem in the mainlist.
- Hide the sidelist when there is no item selected in the main list.
- Deselect items inthe mainlist if the sidelist loses focus.

Furthermore [mx.core.UIComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) is the lightest component that dispatches focus events.

Comment: I can see a problem as the user doesn't necessarily have to click the sidelist. If he never hovers over it, it'll stay visible when not needed.

Comment: Ok, I got it! Adding 3 invisible buttons to the remaining sides will hide the sidelist on their mouse_over event. I updated the post with an image.

Comment: Add focus on the sidelist on roll_over. Then you will receive the focus_out if the user never clicked on the sidelist. Those 3 invisible buttons are blocking interaction, to underlying components. Wich can cause confusion in a later stage.

Comment: On further research,   *...UIComponent does not implement the full IFocusManagerComponent interface since some UIComponents are not intended to receive focus.* from: [IFocusManagerComponent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/IFocusManagerComponent.html).